# Customers load section create in magento2 admin grid

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

I need to create a customer load section in Magento's custom admin grid. I've used the sales order grid as a template for this. While I am able to load the customer, the search functionality isn't working as expected. When attempting to search for a customer, it leads to a blank page. Can someone assist me in resolving this issue?

[image]

In the image above, I've highlighted the customer search section, but upon using it, the page appears blank.

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.